# PokeApi GraphQL limit sprites

Tags: graphql, pokeapi

I'm trying to use the PokeApi graphQL console here https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/console/ to get Pokemon with types and sprites, I've figured out types easy enough but I cant seem to figure out how to limit the sprites to only return the front_default sprite, can anyone help?

**Current Query**

```
query samplePokeAPIquery {
   pokemon_v2_pokemon(
      where: {
        pokemon_v2_pokemontypes: {
          type_id: {_in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}, 
          pokemon_v2_pokemon: {name: {_like: "%%"}}
        }
      }, 
      order_by: {id: asc}, 
      limit: 10, offset: 0) {
    id
    name
    pokemon_v2_pokemonsprites {
     sprites
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
"pokemon_v2_pokemon": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "pokemon_v2_pokemonsprites": [
      {
        "sprites": "{\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/1.png\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/1.png\", \"back_shiny_female\": null, \"other\": {\"dream_world\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/1.svg\", \"front_female\": null}, \"home\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null}, \"official-artwork\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/1.png\"}}, \"versions\": {\"generation-i\": {\"red-blue\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/1.png\", \"front_gray\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/gray/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/back/1.png\", \"back_gray\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/back/gray/1.png\", \"front_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/transparent/1.png\", \"back_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/red-blue/transparent/back/1.png\"}, \"yellow\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/1.png\", \"front_gray\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/gray/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/back/1.png\", \"back_gray\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/back/gray/1.png\", \"front_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/transparent/1.png\", \"back_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-i/yellow/transparent/back/1.png\"}}, \"generation-ii\": {\"crystal\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/shiny/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/back/shiny/1.png\", \"front_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/transparent/1.png\", \"front_shiny_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/transparent/shiny/1.png\", \"back_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/transparent/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/transparent/back/shiny/1.png\"}, \"gold\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/gold/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/gold/shiny/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/gold/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/gold/back/shiny/1.png\", \"front_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/gold/transparent/1.png\"}, \"silver\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/silver/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/silver/shiny/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/silver/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/silver/back/shiny/1.png\", \"front_transparent\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/silver/transparent/1.png\"}}, \"generation-iii\": {\"emerald\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/emerald/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/emerald/shiny/1.png\"}, \"firered-leafgreen\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/firered-leafgreen/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/firered-leafgreen/shiny/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/firered-leafgreen/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/firered-leafgreen/back/shiny/1.png\"}, \"ruby-sapphire\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/ruby-sapphire/1.png\", \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/ruby-sapphire/shiny/1.png\", \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/ruby-sapphire/back/1.png\", \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iii/ruby-sapphire/back/shiny/1.png\"}}, \"generation-iv\": {\"diamond-pearl\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/diamond-pearl/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/diamond-pearl/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/diamond-pearl/back/1.png\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/diamond-pearl/back/shiny/1.png\", \"back_shiny_female\": null}, \"heartgold-soulsilver\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/heartgold-soulsilver/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/heartgold-soulsilver/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/heartgold-soulsilver/back/1.png\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/heartgold-soulsilver/back/shiny/1.png\", \"back_shiny_female\": null}, \"platinum\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/platinum/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/platinum/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/platinum/back/1.png\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-iv/platinum/back/shiny/1.png\", \"back_shiny_female\": null}}, \"generation-v\": {\"black-white\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/back/1.png\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/back/shiny/1.png\", \"back_shiny_female\": null, \"animated\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/animated/1.gif\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/animated/shiny/1.gif\", \"front_shiny_female\": null, \"back_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/animated/back/1.gif\", \"back_female\": null, \"back_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/animated/back/shiny/1.gif\", \"back_shiny_female\": null}}}, \"generation-vi\": {\"omegaruby-alphasapphire\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vi/omegaruby-alphasapphire/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vi/omegaruby-alphasapphire/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null}, \"x-y\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vi/x-y/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vi/x-y/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null}}, \"generation-vii\": {\"ultra-sun-ultra-moon\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vii/ultra-sun-ultra-moon/1.png\", \"front_female\": null, \"front_shiny\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vii/ultra-sun-ultra-moon/shiny/1.png\", \"front_shiny_female\": null}, \"icons\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vii/icons/1.png\", \"front_female\": null}}, \"generation-viii\": {\"icons\": {\"front_default\": \"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-viii/icons/1.png\", \"front_female\": null}}}}"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: think they used Hasura, but set field as a String. They could've used JSON and it would be selectable. But now it is not.

Comment: thanks, add this as an answer and i'll accept it @TalgatSaribayev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they used Hasura, but set field as a `String`. They could've used `JSON` and it would be selectable. But now it is not.

As Ken Chan mentioned there is [open discussion](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/issues/614) on a topic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it is possible. It uses Hasura to generate the GraphQL API and Hasura generates a GraphQL type for each table such that the records in that table can be filtered by using GraphQL query.

But the data type of sprites is just a String type but not a GraphQL type. There are no tables that stores sprites and so it cannot generate a GraphQL type for it. You best bet is to parse the sprites and filter it by yourself.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/issues/614) in their Github talking about it , mainly are :

> It's a bug. Currently, the sprites are the only non-working thing in
> the graphql engine. It's because we don't have a Postgres table for
> them.

> Any update on these being parsed? I added some code on my side to
> parse the sprites object and then choose a specific one that I want,
> but it would be nice to handle that in the GQL query

> No. sorry, updates here will require some actual work and nobody can
> right now